# Shebang line shows up in erb output

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, erb

When I use `#! /usr/bin/env erb` in an executable file `./foo`, the output my the ERB template always shows the shebang line at the top first before the actual ERB output.

I tried *not* using `/usr/bin/env` and directly use `/usr/bin/erb` in my shebang, and other ERB version, but no luck to get rid of the shebang line in my output.

Given:

```
› cat ./foo
#! /usr/bin/env erb
Hello, <%= ARGF.read %>
```

When I run:

```
› ./foo <(echo world)
#! /usr/bin/env erb
Hello,
world
```

But I do *not* want the shebang line to show in the output.

Comment: `ruby` will `cat` your file as it is, except that the content between `<%` and `%>` will be preprocessed by ruby. So, this is expected behavior.

Comment: You could separate template and evaluation, e.g. have a clean template file without a shebang called `foo.erb` and a executable `foo` which evaluates the template.

Answer (score 1):

ERb will process *only* whatever is *inside* ERb tags. Everything else will be passed without change.

So, the only solution you have is to remove the shebang line.